# create and save to a text file using DirectoryChooser

Tags: java, javafx, save

i want to create a text file with a name i input and save that to a location. i can use DirectoryChooser to choose the location but how can i input the file name. is there an option in DirectoryChooser for this.

heres my code

```
public void directoryChooser() {
        DirectoryChooser chooser = new DirectoryChooser();
        chooser.setTitle("Choose location To Save Report"):
        File selectedDirectory = null;
        while(selectedDirectory == null){
        selectedDirectory = chooser.showDialog(null);
        }

        File file = new File(selectedDirectory + "/" + "Report.txt");
        PrintWriter outFile = null;
        try {
            outFile = new PrintWriter(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        for(int i = 0; i<table.getItems().size(); i++){
            outFile.println(table.getItems().get(i).toString());
        }
        outFile.close();
    }
```

so i want it to give me the option to input the name of the file to save.

for example

[image: example]

Comment: Use a `FileChooser`?

Comment: i thought file chooser was only for selecting files?? or selecting the file you want to save to. can file chooser make a new file?

Comment: Yes. `FileChooser` just brings up the regular "Save" dialog when you call `showSaveDialog`.

Comment: It is completely unclear what you are asking. What functionality do you want that is missing from your screen shot?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `DirectoryChooser` lets you choose a directory. If you want to choose a file (**new or existing**), use a `FileChooser`.

```
public void directoryChooser() {
    FileChooser chooser = new FileChooser();
    chooser.setTitle("Choose location To Save Report"):
    File selectedFile = null;
    while(selectedFile== null){
        selectedFile = chooser.showSaveDialog(null);
    }

    File file = new File(selectedFile);
    PrintWriter outFile = null;
    try {
        outFile = new PrintWriter(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    for(int i = 0; i<table.getItems().size(); i++){
        outFile.println(table.getItems().get(i).toString());
    }
    outFile.close();
}
```

Comment: i dont want to choose a file i want to create a file.

Comment: sorry i tried this earlier but i was calling showOpenDialog() didnt spot that u had howSaveDialog(). thats just what i was looking for. thank you